# Will bokeh or plotly libraries work offline in a executable desktop application?

Tags: python, plotly, bokeh, freeze

I'm trying to create an executable in python using either pyqt4 or tkinter and I want my GUI to be able to be interactive. I found bokeh and it seems like it can do everything I want.

However I was reading into bokeh and it seems that its main purpose is to make figures for embedding online using html. I'm not really familiar with html and I want my GUI to be able to pull up all the graphical data within my UI window rather than open an external link.

Is there a way to freeze my python scripts that utilize bokeh or plotly for a desktop application without embedding them online or using html?

Comment: Plotly will work offline, but it generates an html/js document or a <div> element.

Comment: Is it possible to package html/js into an executable and pack it on my GUI window? Sorry not familiar with html enough.

Comment: There are some modules out there that will wrap the html/js into a tkinter element for you